# Does a Swift constructor parentheses work the same way as a Javascript IIFE parentheses?

Tags: javascript, swift, constructor, parentheses, iife

I just started learning `Javascript` and ran across an `Immediately Invoked Function Expression` or `IFFE` for short. The `parentheses` at the end immediately `invokes` the `function`.

```
var greetingsObject = function(name){
  return 'Hello' + name;
}(); //will return Hello undefined
```

In `Swift` I'm also learning how to `programmatically` create objects. I create a `UILabel`

```
var greetingsObject: UILabel = {
 let label = UILabel()
 label.text = "Hello " + nameTextField.text!
 return label
}()
```

My question is does the `parentheses` at the end of the `Swift` object work the same way as the one at the end of the `JS`  `IFFE`? If it doesn't `call` the `function` then what does it do?

Comment: Have you tried it to see what would happen?

Comment: @Alexander I don't understand you question. Have I tried what exactly? The Swift code works fine I just want to know if the construtor's () works the same way as the () in the js iffe.

Comment: You have a hypothesis: "does the parentheses at the end of the Swift object work the same way as the one at the end of the JS  IFFE?". Expanding out the meaning of JS IFFE, we get the equivalent question: "does the parentheses at the end of the Swift closure invokes the closure"? What steps have you taken towards testing your hypothesis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I first to point out a bug with your example: your code reference `nameTextField` within the initializer for `greetingObject`. There's no guarantee what property will be initialized first so you can't reference another property within the init closure.

Having said that, it works the same in Swift as Javascript. `greetingsObject` will be initialized when you initialize the class instance. This pawttern is usually employed when you want the property to be initialzed only once and shared among multiple instances.

Swift also extended the concept with an optional `lazy` modifier. With `lazy`, it will initialize the property the first time you reference it.

```
class ViewController : UIViewController {
    lazy var greetingsObject: UILabel = {
        print("Initialzing greetingsObject")

        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Hello World"
        return label
    }()
}

let vc = ViewController() // `greetingsObject` is not yet initialized

print("First reference to greetingsObject")
vc.greetingsObject.text   // it will be initialized here
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. About your first comment. Why isn't there a guarantee which property will be initialized first? I know lazy initializes an object only when it's first called. Are you saying that if nameTextField gets initialized before the greetingsObject (or vice versa) that's where the crash will occur and that's why it shouldn't get referenced in the closure?

Comment: The only place where you can be sure that a property has been initilized before another property is inside an `init` function. Notihing in the language says that Swift will initialize `nameTextField` (perhaps by connecting an outlet) before `greetingsObject` so you may be using an uninitialized object

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good explanation of the Swift closure's  parenthese

https://medium.com/the-traveled-ios-developers-guide/swift-initialization-with-closures-5ea177f65a5#.89xqavhii